# Why when i put a margin-top on a div on the other one the BODY takes it too?

Tags: html, css

I dont understand why when i put the margin-top at class="container", the margin-top is token by the all div class="navbar-fixed z-depth-0 blue"

```css
.navbar-fixed {
    height: 200px;
}

.col.s12.a {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#cnt{
    margin-top:50px; 
}
```

```html
    <div id="nav" class="navbar-fixed z-depth-0 blue">
        <div id="cnt" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col l6" style="border:1px solid black">
                    <h4>aaa</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col l6" style="border:1px solid black">
                    <h4>ss</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Margin collapse http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: I strongly suspect you're the victim of margin collapse.

Comment: Just for grins, give your outer container a border and see what happens.

Comment: @zzzzBov i have to be victim for all life or there is a solution? :D

Comment: @J.arc Put padding on your body instead of margin on your outer wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

What you have is [collapsed margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins). In your particularly case you can put padding on `#nav` instead of margin on `#cnt`:

```
#nav { padding-top: 50px; }
```